# Install DSPACE6 - mirage2 local customisations failure

Tags: linux, centos, dspace

I'm installing DSPACE under centos 6
I've install all required dependencies and performed a mvn package successfull.

Now I have problems in this steap: Enabling and building the Mirage 2 theme.
The next command work fine: mvn package -Dmirage2.on=true
but this: mvn package -Dmirage2.on=true -Dmirage2.deps.included=false not work. The next error show:

```
<p>npm WARN package.json Mirage2@0.1.2 No description<br>
  npm WARN package.json Mirage2@0.1.2 No repository field.<br>
  npm WARN package.json Mirage2@0.1.2 No README data<br>
  npm WARN package.json string_decoder@1.0.3 string_decoder is also the name of a node core module.<br>
  npm WARN prefer global coffee-script@1.10.0 should be installed with -g<br>
  npm WARN cannot run in wd Mirage2@0.1.2 bower install (wd=/home/dspace/dspace-6.1-release/dspace/modules/xmlui-mirage2/target/themes/Mirage2)<br>
  [INFO] ------ (Mirage2) org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec<br>
  Running &quot;copy:classic_mirage_color_scheme&quot; (copy) task<br>
  Copied 1 file</p>
<p>Running &quot;compass:prod&quot; (compass) task<br>
  Warning: Command failed: /bin/sh: /usr/bin/compass: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory<br>
  Use --force to continue.</p>
<p>Aborted due to warnings.<br>
</p>
<p>Execution Time (2017-07-21 10:35:38 UTC-4)<br>
  loading tasks                 692ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 80%<br>
  copy:classic_...color_scheme   33ms  ▇▇ 4%<br>
  compass:prod                  137ms  ▇▇▇▇▇ 16%<br>
  Total 862ms</p>
<p>[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
  [INFO] Reactor Summary:<br>
  [INFO]<br>
  [INFO] DSpace Parent Project .............................. SUCCESS [  1.310 s]<br>
  [INFO] DSpace Addon Modules ............................... SUCCESS [  0.008 s]<br>
  [INFO] DSpace Kernel :: Additions and Local Customizations  SUCCESS [  6.335 s]<br>
  [INFO] DSpace XML-UI Mirage2 Theme :: Local Customisations  FAILURE [  8.991 s]<br>
  [INFO] DSpace XML-UI (Manakin) :: Local Customizations .... SKIPPED<br>
  [INFO] DSpace JSP-UI :: Local Customizations .............. SKIPPED<br>
  [INFO] DSpace RDF :: Local Customizations ................. SKIPPED<br>
  [INFO] DSpace REST :: Local Customizations ................ SKIPPED<br>
  [INFO] DSpace SWORD :: Local Customizations ............... SKIPPED<br>
  [INFO] DSpace SWORD v2 :: Local Customizations ............ SKIPPED<br>
  [INFO] DSpace SOLR :: Local Customizations ................ SKIPPED<br>
  [INFO] DSpace OAI-PMH :: Local Customizations ............. SKIPPED<br>
  [INFO] DSpace Assembly and Configuration .................. SKIPPED<br>
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
  [INFO] BUILD FAILURE<br>
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
  [INFO] Total time: 17.472 s<br>
  [INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-21T10:35:39-04:00<br>
  [INFO] Final Memory: 36M/355M<br>
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.soebes.maven.plugins:iterator-maven-plugin:0.3:iterator (default) on project xmlui-mirage2: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 6 (Exit value: 6) -&gt; [Help 1]<br>
  [ERROR]<br>
  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.<br>
  [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.<br>
  [ERROR]<br>
  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:<br>
  [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException<br>
  [ERROR]<br>`enter code here`
  [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command<br>
  [ERROR]   mvn &lt;goals&gt; -rf :xmlui-mirage2</p>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

The following warning makes me suspect that ruby is not installed.

```
Warning: Command failed: /bin/sh: /usr/bin/compass: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory<br> Use --force to continue.</p>
```

Could you check your ruby installation? What output do you get when you execute the following command in the command line?

```
ruby -v
```

If the above command does not output a ruby version, then ruby is not installed. You can install ruby by executing the following command in the command line:

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```